# Angular material timepicker insert a minute gap

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15

I have this material component in Angular 15.

```
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>{{'DOCTOR_AREA.START_TIME' | translate}} </mat-label>
                <input type="time" matInput  min="08:00" max="20:00" id="StartTime" formControlName="StartTime" [(ngModel)]="currentSlot.StartTime"/>
              </mat-form-field>
```

I need to insert a minute gap of 30 minutes.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#step) attribute with value of `1800` seconds:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>{{'DOCTOR_AREA.START_TIME' | translate}} </mat-label>
    <input type="time" matInput min="08:00" max="20:00" step="1800" id="StartTime" formControlName="StartTime" [(ngModel)]="currentSlot.StartTime"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi, I try but nothing change

Comment: Of course something happens. Highlight the minute portion in the field and use keyboard's `↑` or `↓` keys to see it in action.